# Why android ffmpeg takes so long time to resize mp4 video from high resolution?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm resizing **~30 sec** long (~59.98 MB) **mp4** video with resolution of **1920 X 1080** to **1280 X 720** using following `ffmpeg` command in android.

```
["-i", inputVideo!!.path, "-vf", "scale=720:1280", outputVideo.path, "-hide_banner"]
```

converted video output is very good (~6.6MB). but, `ffmpeg` conversion take so much time. Is there any options available that I can reduce the conversion time?

**update**

If output format is other than `mp4`. it is fine but, conversion time must be reduce.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add `-preset:v veryfast`

Comment: Thanks @Gyan, do you means `["-i", inputVideo!!.path, "-vf", "-preset:v", "veryfast", "scale=720:1280", outputVideo.path, "-hide_banner"]`. Right?

Comment: No, after the scale.

Comment: @Gyan, OK, Thanks a lot brother.

Comment: @Gyan Hello, I have ended up using `["-i", inputVideo!!.path, "-c:v", "libx264", "-crf", "23", "-maxrate", "900K", "-bufsize", "2M", "-vf", "scale=720:1280", "-preset:v", "veryfast", "-movflags", "+faststart", outputVideo.path]`. but, all those additional flags keep reducing video size. But, not reducing the conversion time. What I want is reducing conversion time, output video size is not matter. Thanks.